# Jenkins Pipeline Plugin don't display script text area

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins 2.19.1 on  my Ubuntu16.04.
And I have installed Pipeline Plugin.

But my script text area is **disappear**.

[image]

Do anyone know why?

Thanks

Comment: Due to some bug located who knows where. Fastest way to find out would be to open Web Developer tools in Firefox (Ctrl+Shift+I or F12) and to look at JavaScript errors and DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regression. See [JENKINS-39154](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39154).

Answer (score 0):

This happen in 2.46.3 too if ace-editor is not correctly loaded.

Solution: Download ace-editor from jenkins plugins site and install it manually in the Manage Plugins page.